# How to create a Gradle Action object in Kotlin

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

I need to pass an object of type `org.gradle.api.Action` to some function.

How can I create such an object in Kotlin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply place the word `Action` before a Kotlin lambda:

```
Action {
    myParam: String ->
         println(myParam)
}
```

You will need to import `org.gradle.api.Action` of course.